# How to describe an object type that can have additional properties apart from specific ones?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I have a data type called User currently, and I want it to have two mandatory properties, name and age. In addition, users should be able to add any number of other properties to it. How should I describe it in JSDoc to support this requirement without encountering errors?

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} User
 * @property {string} name - user name
 * @property {number} age -user age
 */

/**
 * @type {User}
 */
const tom={
  name:'cx',
  age:25,
  from:'sh',// error
  to:'bj',// error
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can add a {*} property similar to the any-type described [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) to get rid of the error

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} User
 * @property {string} name - User name (mandatory)
 * @property {number} age - User age (mandatory)
 * @property {*} [key: value] - Additional properties that users can add (optional)
 */

/**
 * @type {User}
 */
const tom = {
  name: 'cx',
  age: 25,
  from: 'sh', // No error
  to: 'bj', // No error
};
```

Edit: after some searching, I've found [this thread](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1199). Could you check if this resolves the errors

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} User
 * @property {string} name user name
 * @property {number} age user age
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object.<string, string>} Descriptor
 * @typedef {User & Descriptor} UserWithDetails user with details
 */


/**
 * @type {UserWithDetails}
 */
const tom = {
  name: "cx",
  age: 25,
  from: "sh",
  to: "bj",
};
```

Edit on edit: If the above works perhaps you can even simplify it by doing

```
/**
 * @typedef {object} User
 * @property {string} name - User name
 * @property {number} age - User age
 * @property {Object.<string, string>} [additionalProperties] - Additional key-value pairs
 */

/**
 * @type {User}
 */
const tom = {
  name: "cx",
  age: 25,
  from: "sh",
  to: "bj",
};
```

Comment: thanks,but according to your coding style, vscode still shows an error suggesting that the object `from` does not exist.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some new insights. hope it helps!

Comment: awesome, and you are welcome :) Did the simplified version work as well? then I can edit my answer to just contain this